# Find the number of roots of $z^2 - \cos z=0$ for $|z| < 2$ using Rouche's theorem

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, inequality, rouches-theorem

> Find the number of roots for the following equation for $|z| < 2$, $z\in \Bbb C$:
> $$
> z^2 - \cos z=0
> $$

The reasoning below is based on using Rouche's theorem. So basically I picked two functions $f(z)$ and $\phi(z)$ such that:
$$
f(z) = z^2\\
\phi(z) = \cos z
$$

Now I need to show that $|f(z)| > |\phi(z)|$ for $|z| = 2$. My main issue here is proving that statement.

Consider $|z^2|$, clearly the absolute value is $4$. For $|\cos z|$ and $y\in[-2,2]$:
$$
\begin{align}
|\cos z| &= \left|\frac{e^{iz} + e^{-iz}}{2}\right| \\
&= {1\over 2}\left|e^{ix - y} + e^{-ix+y}\right| \\
&\le {1\over 2}\left(\left|e^{ix}\right|\left|e^{-y}\right| + \left|e^{-ix}\right|\left|e^{y}\right|\right)\\
&={1\over 2}\left(e^{-y}+e^y\right)
\end{align}
$$

Now $|\cos z|$ is symmetric with respect to $x = 0$ so we might consider only one case: $y \in [0;2]$. Take a look at the following equation:
$$
\begin{align}
{1\over 2}\left(e^{-y} + e^y\right) &= 4 \\
e^{-y} + e^y &= 8 \ \ | \times e^y \\
e^{2y} - 8e^y + 1 &= 0
\end{align}
$$
Solve for $e^y$:
$$
e^y = 4\pm \sqrt{15}
$$

Approximate calculations show that:
$$
\begin{align}
y = \ln(4+\sqrt{15}) &\approx 2,06343... > 2\\
y = \ln(4-\sqrt{15}) &\approx -2,06343... < -2
\end{align}
$$

Finally since ${1\over 2}\left(e^{-y}+e^y\right)$ is incresing for $y \in [0,2]$ we have that:
$$
|\cos z| = {1\over 2}\left(e^{-y}+e^y\right) < 4, \forall y\in[0,2]
$$

This means the equation has two roots (with multiplicities) in $|z| < 2$.

> The question here is how do I show
> $$
> \ln(4+\sqrt{15}) > 2\\
> \ln(4-\sqrt{15}) < -2
> $$
> Also, I would appreciate it if someone could show a simpler solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already figured out that for $z=x+iy$
$$
 |\cos(z)| \le \cosh(y)
$$
and that $\cosh(y)$ is increasing in $y$ for $y \ge 0$. Therefore
$$
 |\cos(z)| \le  \cosh(2) = \frac{e^2+e^{-2}}{2}
$$
for $|z| =2$, and it suffices to show that $e^2+e^{-2} < 8$:
$$
e^2+e^{-2} < 2.8^2 + \frac 1{2.5^2} = 7.84 + 0.16 = 8 \, .
$$

It follows that $z^2 - \cos(z)$ and $z^2$ have the same number of zeros in $|z| < 2$ (counting multiplicities), that is $2$.

Comment: Nice pick for approximate values of $e$. Thanks!